# Google Meet Screen Share on Huwawei T8 Not Working even w/ Storage & Microphone Permissions

Tags: google-meet

asking for a friend. She has **Android** running on a tablet **Huwawei T8** which has **Quick App Center** installed for **Google Meet**. It works perfectly fine for google meet meetings and it can view screen shares from other devices. The only problem is that if it is the Host and attempts doing the Screen Sharing, it will not work. Pressing Screen Share will do nothing with no error messages. I've done some googling and found out that you definitely have to give Quick App Center the `Storage` and `Microphone` Permissions, but despite giving it ALL permissions (i.e `Camera`, `Location`, `Calendar`, etc) in the `Privacy Settings` it is still not working with NO error messages. So we are in the dark. Any ideas what we are missing?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, from [this article](https://www.techinfoin.com/google-meet-on-huawei/), looks like this Google Meet is actually a web-based version contained inside an app, not a native app?

Comment: thank you for your help! yeah you're right it looks like its a wrapper app